# How to organize nettty pipeline?

Tags: java, netty

My pipeline doesn't work as expected

```
public class DataServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Command.CommandMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Data.DataMessage.getDefaultInstance()));

        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());
        
        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new CommandHandler());
        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DataHandler());
    }
}
```

DataHandler is ignored fully